Lenovo P14s (gen 4) heating problems after upgrade to 24.04
I upgraded 23.10 to 24.04 (was prompted), and straight after it started just rebooting. Poof, black screen. Rebooting.
I am not too familiar with debugging the logs or journalctl but couldn't find any traces of dumps.
After a lot of trial and error I started suspecting that heat was an issue. So I reached for thinkfan. And after installing and running for a while temperatures seems much better regulated.
I still do get some spontaneous reboots under heavy load though. So any pointers as to why this happens after the upgrade is appreciated. I didn't follow temps and fan speeds before the upgrade as I didn't have to. :)

I have downgraded to 23.10 for now. Heat management seems MUCH better, so seems like 24.01 actually was generating much more load as well.

Had the same happen to me on a Lenovo P14s gen2. Mine has a Nvidia Quadro GPU as well as an integrated Intel graphics.
Apparently after the upgrade to 24.04 Nvidia graphics was active and was generating much more heat.
You can check via
sudo prime-select query

Tho check which GPU is in use. In my case it said on-demand which I'm not sure what it means. I tried changing to Intel via
sudo prime-select intel

And then rebooting.
For me that didn't work. So I went into "Software & Updates" > "Additional Drivers". I had nvidia-driver-535 selected here. I switched it to nouveau and rebooted. That dropped my temperatures by about 15-20°C and the fan is spinning as before the upgrade.

Yeah, since I posted this it actually seems the issues is the Nvidia driver and not the heating. Seems impossible to run Nvidia on Ubuntu, I try every once in a while, but always end up with spontaneous reboots. :-(

BTW: On-demand means it will activate the GPU when it things it is necessary. :-)

I had the same problems with my ThinkPad T14s Gen 3 + Ubuntu 22.04.
Strange symptoms like described here:
Lenovo ThinkPad P14s Gen 4 randomly reboots, same with P16s Gen 2 (Nvidia RTX A500)
My solution is very easy: just disable "Memory Protection" in BIOS.
Now my laptop is quite more stable. No reboots already for a few days and no extra heating anymore. It's a long period for my type of usage :)
Hope my experience may be useful for you.
Thank you.

Disabling "Memory Protection" might make your system more vulnerable to certain security threats. It is generally recommended only for troubleshooting or compatibility purposes.
